# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, exc-bad-access

I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE sometimes in the following method:

```
+ (NSString *) UTCStringWithDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    NSLocale *enLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

    [dateFormatter setLocale:enLocale];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return dateString;
}
```

What could be going wrong? Please help!

Comment: there's nothing wrong with that method. The usage is probably incorrect somewhere.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with that method. I got correct log also. Check your call.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from the description which line is crashing, so this is my best guess:

It's probably something is sometimes wrong with the incoming NSDate argument.

If there is a race condition for the date, it may be getting released and its RAM location is filled with a new object before this method begins or just after it begins.

Try running your code with NSZombies activated or try checking that it is still an NSDate object just before using it.

```
NSAssert( [date isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]], @"Error, expected 'NSDate', but argument class was '%@'", NSStringFromClass([date class]) ); 
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```